# Did Apollo astronauts spend any time on the lunar surface during lunar night?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, lunar-landing

Are there any images from the surface of the moon during lunar night?  Preferably taken by Apollo astronauts, but otherwise by rovers etc showing "earthshine" on the lunar surface?

I found this example from Apollo 17, but it is from the CSM, and I think it's from before landing?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AS17-158-23902.jpg
[image]

Comment: No. For a time, night landings were in fact considered for the Sun for obvious reasons, but on the Moon they'd just leave scientists in the dark.

Comment: @uhoh: Uh... night time landings for the sun? How would *that* work? :-D

Comment: @DevSolar Perhaps "Did NASA consider for a time a mission to land on the Sun *at night?*" would be a good Skeptics SE question... next April?

Comment: @uhoh I guess that was [Poe's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe's_law) at work then. ;-)

Comment: All of the Apollo landings happened a day (24 hours) or so after sunrise at the landing site; this was intentional as it was thought to make landing easier. The missions only lasted a few days to avoid having the astronauts be on the Moon at lunar noon.

Comment: @DevSolar It would be too bright and hot to do it during the day.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Now that you mention it, of course you'd *land on the sun at night*... what was I thinking... 

Comment: @DevSolar I'm still looking for a video recording of Buzz Aldrin's telling of the story; in it's original context Poe's law would be a poor fit.. But here in ASCIIville, yes indeed!

Comment: This is why that line from Santana's *Smooth* always bothered me: *"Like seven inches from the midday sun"*...  At that distance, does it even matter what time of day it is?  How would you even define time of day from that location?

Comment: @uhoh that's short-sighted thinking though. In fact the only way you could possibly manage to land on the sun is by using the radiation pressure for braking. Without that, no amount of fuel could possibly feather the landing. But at night there's no radiation pressure, so you'd die.

Comment: Since the density of the Sun starts at zero and increases extremely slowly (see [Does the Sun's atmosphere have a scale height?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/30232/7982) and [What is the density profile within the Sun's photosphere? Which one of these is wrong?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32727/7982) and [At what depth below the Sun's surface does the density reach that of water?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32729/7982) ) one might look into the possibility of "aero"braking, but ya, "so you'd die" still applies.

Comment: I spent all one night wondering where the sun had gone. It wasn't 'til the next morning it dawned on me.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Unfortunately, no.**

All the Apollo missions took place during Lunar "day". Specifically, mission planners targeted landing times just after Lunar sunrise so that the sun's low angle would cast long shadows and simplify depth-perception and thus landing on the rough surface.

[Here is a list of all the missions, and the angles of the sun above the horizon during them.](https://history.nasa.gov/alsj/alsj-sunangles.html)

Night time missions were not seriously considered for multiple reasons:

- No PR benefit: A large aim of the Apollo program was to show the world what the USA could do, and filming at night would've been difficult with the comparatively primitive camera equipment of the time.
- Minimal science benefit. Off the top of my head, I can't think of any real advantages that a night-time moon mission would have, besides maybe investigating the thermal cycle that occurs and maybe some dawn/dusk exosphere observations. Apollo was big on samples
- Engineering problems. Apollo missions occurred in ye olden times before we had power efficient illumination; specifically LEDs. Illuminating enough area to land and perform surface activities was outside of the power budget available to suits and ships at the time. Also, engineering the lander to withstand the temps of lunar night would've introduced additional problems

Comment: Not to mention the heating requirements for being at -130ºC for an extended period of time. (Obviously not all places on the moon have that temperature at night. But it's an estimate for the equatorial average temperature)

Comment: @Massagran since the moon doesn't have an atmosphere, I don't see how that's any different than the _theoretically_ low temperature they would've had while not on the moon.

Comment: @Cubic Being in space, and being on the lit surface of the moon is kinda the same. Being on the dark side of the moon is different.

Comment: @Cubic In open space, roughly half of the ship is warmed by direct sunlight.  On the night side of the moon, the only heat the craft will receive is radiated from the lunar surface as it cools, and whatever minuscule amount it received from distant stars.

Comment: @Cubic  heat is transferred by conduction, convection and radiation.  An atmosphere conducts heat; one must also consider radiation of heat.  The ancient Romans made ice in the desert by digging large pits, insulating them with straw, putting water in shields and uncovering them at night to radiate heat to interstellar space.

Comment: @Technophile: [citation needed]

Comment: @TonyK  just Google "heat conduction convection radiation"; any basic physics textbook; https://sciencenotes.org/heat-transfer-conduction-convection-radiation/, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer, ...

Comment: @Technophile Actually it was the Persians who invented [yakhchāls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakhch%C4%81l) - the Romans simply used slaves to hack ice out of nearby mountains.

Comment: @Technophile: since the second law of thermodynamics says things don't get colder than their surroundings without use of energy I'll assume your sense of humour is just as corny as mine.

Comment: @Technophile: I've read your links, but I don't see anything about Romans making ice in their shields. Are you sure these Romans weren't just taking advantage of sub-zero overnight ambient temperatures?

Comment: @holdenweb Evaporative cooling is sufficient to both lower water near its freezing point *to* its freezing point, as well as remove the latent heat of fusion in order to facilitate the phase change.

Comment: @TonyK  sorry, I misunderstood which portion you were asking about.  I was told this by a mechanical engineer a long time ago; one source found is https://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/nov99/941723540.Sh.r.html.  He wrote that "My source is Reay Tannahill's Food in History."

Comment: @Technophile: Thanks, I think that counts as a citation :-) But they didn't put water in their shields, like you claimed; according to your link, they used the shields for insulation during the day. And "to radiate heat to interstellar space" is purely your own invention.

Comment: @TonyK  I did have the shield usage wrong, however I believe that this is what I was told at the time.  Re radiation, try going outside on a clear vs. overcast winter's night.  Clouds keep heat in.  The difference is quite dramatic.  Citation:  https://www.rochesterfirst.com/weather/weather-glossary/radiational-cooling-defined-the-rapid-loss-of-heat-from-earths-surface/

Answer (score 21):

The [Moon has a cycle](https://www.space.com/moon-missions-artemis-challenges-overnight) of 14 days of daylight (14 days of continuous sunlight) and 14 days of night (14 days of continuous dark and cold).

All the Apollo lunar missions landed when each mission site was in full daylight. The astronauts did not experience night on the Moon.

In late 1967, the [Surveyor 5](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/surveyor-5/in-depth/) Moon lander took 20 000 photos of its landing site over 4 Lunar days. None were taken during the night.

> Surveyor 5 was, however, the most successful of the series so far. The lander returned 18,006 photos before lunar night descended on Sept. 24, 1967. Controllers successfully commanded the vehicle to take another 1,000 photographs during the second lunar day between Oct. 15 and Oct. 24, 1967, and the fourth lunar day in December. In total, 20,018 pictures were transmitted.

Similarly in 1968, [Surveyor 7](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/lunar/missions/surveyor/) only took photos during the day. After the first lunar day, where it took 20 000 photos,

> Operation of the spacecraft was terminated 80 hours after sunset. The spacecraft was reactivated for the second lunar day on February 12, 1968, and operated until February 21, 1968.

Comment: One could mention more recent rovers also. [Chang'e 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e_3) and [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e_4) are active on the moon right now, but Wikipedia seems to suggest they go into a 'sleep mode' at night, presumably due to the lack of solar power, so they might not provide any night time photos either.

Comment: @N.Virgo: And why would they, there isn't anything there to see that isn't better visible at lunar day. Other than the stars, of course, but they are not on the moon to make pictures of those. ;-)

Comment: Given that there's no wind, I think it would be interesting to see a photo taken overnight using slow shutter speed if necessary to approximate what Earthshine would look like to a human on the moon at night.

Comment: @tomh Brighter than moonlight. The earth is much larger, and the moon has no atmosphere getting in the way. As for photos "showing" that, it's a matter of exposure and how much you'd brighten the picture in post. It wouldn't be a good proof / example either way.

Comment: I'd like to see it. I understand how exposure works.  A day/night comparison of the same lunar landscape taken from the surface shown with Earthshine instead of sunshine would be interesting to me...